# "background-clip" not working?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox, modernizr

Was looking at [this](http://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/) as I wanted to make my image into text. According to what it says, in other browsers, the text should be the colour you set it as and there'd be no background (unless I misread).

Anyhow, on Chrome, it seems to work perfectly as stated though on other browsers, the fallback of using Modernizr is not working. It adds the class of `backgroundclip` regardless. All browsers are returning true. Even on the [Mozilla Developer Network it's saying that browsers support this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) even though this is not the case.

What Firefox and other browsers are doing is displaying the background. This is a problem for me as the image I'm using as text is practically all white with a slight pattern through it. So white on white with a slight pattern isn't exactly easy to see.

Things I've tried:

```
background-clip:text;
-moz-background-clip:text;
```

Neither of these two worked.

What I need is either a way to get `background-clip` working in other browsers (at least Firefox) OR to get it working as intended. Having the image as text in Chrome and plain colour for other browsers. Is there something I can do/use, to get this?

Comment: is text-shadow something you could use to stroke your text with a dark color ?

Comment: @GCyrillus Yes, I can do that however it's not what I'm asking.

Comment: I was thinking as a fallback, else , SVG can do that : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Dqcio (used for another question here less than a week ago :) ) remove background-image or fill text with another one

Comment: mozilla doesn't say it supports the value `text` , wich is a non standard value introduced by webkit

Comment: @GCyrillus I must've skipped over that. Still doesn't help me though.

Comment: At this time, i believe its about only SVG that can help you :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/199 for background](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/199).

Basically, Modernizr was previously detecting background-clip by itself, which lead to issues like the one we have here. [A standalone test for background-clip: text now exists](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/css/backgroundcliptext.js), which you should be able to pluck out and use in the current pre 3.0 releases.

Comment: The way you actually download Modernizr confuses me. How do I actually get a version with this test? I haven't seen an option for it on their website.

Comment: That is becuase it is in the pre 3.0 release. It has not been released on the website. You would want to clone the current git repo, and build it using grunt.